# Как сделать английский язык языком по умолчанию для моего приложения?

Tags: android, распознавание-речи

Мое приложение использует Speech To Text recognition, если я меняю язык в настройках на русский, оно перестает корректно работать, так как язык распознавания так же меняется на русский. Как сделать, чтобы вне зависимости от языка системы, в моем приложении использовался английский?

Я пробовал этот вариант, но он не работает:

```
Locale myLocale;
    myLocale = new Locale("English (US)", "en_US");
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button recognizeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    recognizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View context) {
    final DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale("en");
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ENGLISH);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String str="";
        for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
            str+= results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("Mercedes")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
        }else{
            speechText.setText("It's not: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
final Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("en");
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Этот код гарантировано работает, пользуюсь им сам. После этого нужно пересоздать все `View` (в случае `Activity` вызвать `setContentView()`), чтобы они подтянули новые ресурсы. Можно конечно и вручную записать новые ресурсы во `View`.

Comment: не могли бы вы проинспектировать мой код? У меня ваш вариант не работает.

Comment: @Николай слишком много неправильно, чтобы инспектировать. Вкорне все неправильно.

Comment: мой код правильный, я брал его из книги "Learning Android Intents Explore and apply the power of intents in Android application development - 2014". За исключением метода setContentView. Просто ваша часть, как я понял, подходит для другого подхода, вопрос в том, как и куда его вставить, чтобы он заработал, если есть возможность, не могли бы вы поделиться ссылкой, где реализуется ваш подход?